# VIM Solarized colorscheme not working correctly

Tags: vim, neovim

Im using the Windows Terminal from the Windows Store, I tried installing the solarized colorscheme with vim-plug, and its not working correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aRnB.png)

It looks grey-ish and I'm not sure why its not working.
This is my init.vim file:

```
 call plug#begin(stdpath('data') . '/plugged')
     Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
 call plug#end()
 
 
 set nu
 set tabstop=4
 set shiftwidth=4
 
 syntax enable
 let g:solarized_termcolors=256
 set background=dark
 colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: The picture you linked looks pretty much like the Solarized color scheme to me.... I am not sure what you think is wrong with it. This might get a better response over on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The syntax highlighting is correct but the background is showing as grey, I'm not sure why its not that deep blue solarized has

Comment: Try moving "set background=dark" to *after* "colorscheme solarized"